# Why does the TensorFlow Estimator API take inputs as a lambda?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow-estimator

The `tf.estimator` API takes input "input functions" that return `Dataset`s. For example, `Estimator.train()` takes an `input_fn` ([documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/Estimator#train)).

In the examples I've seen, whenever this function is supplied manually, it is an argumentless lambda.

Doesn't that mean that the function always returns the same value? Or is it invoked multiple times with no arguments? I wasn't able to find documentation about this. Why don't functions like `train()` just take input as a `Dataset` explicitly?

Comment: According to those docs, the input is any function, not necessarily a lambda (which would be a rather ridiculous restriction). "Doesn't that mean that the function always returns the same value?" no, not necessarily. e.g. `lambda: random.random()`. Note, if you follow the [link in those docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/premade_estimators#create_input_functions) it shows two examples, neither of which are lambda functions, and one of which takes arguments. I suppose passing a function that returns a `Dataset` gives more flexibility.

Comment: Yes, I really meant "why is it a function". If you're referring to train_input_fn by your link, it's not a counterexample - it's not being passed directly to train (), it's being wrapped in an argumentless function so my question still applies. What's the flexibility you have in mind?

Answer (score 3):

`Dataset` objects are also backed by nodes in the computational graph. The `Estimator` constructs the computational graph on each all to `train()`, `evaluate()` etc.  By doing so the `Estimator` API ensures that operations on different `Estimator` objects are isolated and `Tensor`/`Dataset` into independent graphs.

Some code pointers (for TensorFlow 1.7) in case you're interested:

- `Estimator.train()` eventually invokes [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.7/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py#L813)
- Which in turn [invokes `input_fn`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.7/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py#L662)

Hope that helps.

Comment: But I pass input_fn to train. Does a single call to train invoke it multiple times?

Comment: No (updated the comment). Each call to `Estimator.train()` will create a new graph and fill it in (by invoking `input_fn` and `model_fn` and connecting them together). (Edited my answer above to make that clearer). If `Estimator.train()` took `Tensor` or `Dataset` objects then it could easily lead to errors like where the graph in which the user created the `Tensor` or `Dataset` object for input would be different from the graph in which the computation specified by `model_fn` is created.

Comment: Oh I see, so these functions are invoked in the context of a graph being built internally by train() and that's why we don't want people to directly supply a tensor or dataset but rather want them to be reconstructed in the context of that graph? Then, is it an error to supply a function that returns a Dataset that's already been built and belongs to another graph?

Comment: Strictly speaking, I think that is true. However, the implementation of the Python `Dataset` class I think creates the graph nodes lazily, so it _might_ still work if you return the same Python object. But you really shouldn't do that (and [official](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/r1.7.0/official/resnet/imagenet_main.py#L157) [examples](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/r1.7.0/official/mnist/mnist.py#L197) [don't](https://github.com/tensorflow/tpu/blob/6038242542fc8ff21f19d3c04bea214bc907d214/models/official/retinanet/dataloader.py#L106) either). Hope that helps.

Comment: Yeah, thank you, this clarifies how I should use it. I just don't understand why the API was designed this way - it feels very unusual and unnecessary. Hopefully someone can chime in with a more complete explanation of the reasoning.

Answer (score 1):

According to Tensorflow documentation:

"Estimators expect an input_fn to take no arguments. To work around this restriction, we use lambda to capture the arguments and provide the expected interface."

https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets_for_estimators

Comment: I guess this pushes the real question down the road: why do estimators take a lambda instead of the value it returns :)